# PHP - Using mod_rewrite in Apache

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have the following URL:

http://example.com/pages/page.php?company_name=Name

What I want to achieve is to have a URL like this:

http://example.com/pages/Name

I have tried different rules but they don't work:

```
RewriteRule ^pages/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /pages/page.php?company_name=$1 [NC] or

RewriteRule ^pages/([^/]*)\.php$ /pages/page.php?company_name=$1 [L]
```

It doesn't work. It gives me a "not found" page. How can I properly use mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
RewriteRule ^pages/([0-9a-zA-Z\-_]*)(/|)$ /pages/page.php?company_name=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This will care or not care if the url has a trailing slash:

```
http://example.com/pages/Name
http://example.com/pages/Name/
```

And will also include any extra agrs (QSA) if the page calls for it:

```
http://example.com/pages/Name/?more=stuff
```

That should work, if your apache has mod_rewrite and the php exists where you have shown.

UPDATE

If you have a different url that needs a different php, for example 'bluepages':

```
http://example.com/bluepages/Name
```

Then this would work for that:

```
RewriteRule ^bluepages/([0-9a-zA-Z\-_]*)(/|)$ /bluepages/somescript.php?some_var=$1 [QSA,L]
```

If you have multiple like this you wish to control, you can make multiple RewriteRules in your htaccess for each one. However if you just want to wildcard it, then this would do a blind catchall (and cause lots of error reports in your apache logs):

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z\-_]*)(/|)$ /$1/page.php?some_var=$2 [QSA,L]
```

You will either need to be specific, or just change everything. There are so many ways one can go with it, and it really depends on your intent.

Comment: I tried the above option but it still doesn't work, still give me the "Not Found
The requested URL /bluepages/Name.php was not found on this server. I would like to know does the folder structure matter? Because I have root/pages folder where my .htaccess and remaining php files are located. Thanks

Comment: The above will work for the example you provided. If you are doing something other than what you provided, then my answer will not work. You mention now bluepages, and root/pages... all these things come into play and should have been added to your original question.

Comment: Thanks for the update, it works now. Based on what you provided, I will try a couple of options/scenarios and see what result it gives. Thanks again!